# How to get all distinct values of all columns but keep the original table structure?

Tags: sql, odata, hana

I have a table with 5 columns in HANA.The table name is students and following are the fields- name, age, address,gender,score.I need to get the distinct values of each of the columns.For eg, the table is-

```
      Name  Age  Address  Gender  Score
      A      1     abc      F      10
      C      3     abc      M      10
      B      2     def      M      5
      C      3     ghi      F      10
      D      2     def      M      5
```

Expected results is-

```
      Name  Age  Address  Gender  Score
      A      1     abc      F      10
      B      2     def      M      5
      C      3     ghi
```

Please suggest how to achieve this using views or odata.None of the discussions available seem to be useful.I do not want UNION  because it combines all the values into one column in the result.

Comment: WIth that sample table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: I think you have a typo in your expected results for `Age`. Anyway, does the order of values matter to you, or is what you put into the question just one particular valid result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to Hana, but this might do the job

```
select      min (name)    as name
           ,min (Age)     as Age
           ,min (Address) as Address
           ,min (Gender)  as Gender
           ,min (Score)   as Score

from        (           select Name ,Age  ,Address ,Gender ,Score ,1000000000  as n                     from students where 1=2

            union all   select Name ,null ,null    ,null   ,null  ,row_number() over (order by Name)    from students group by Name
            union all   select null ,Age  ,null    ,null   ,null  ,row_number() over (order by Age)     from students group by Age
            union all   select null ,null ,Address ,null   ,null  ,row_number() over (order by Address) from students group by Address
            union all   select null ,null ,null    ,Gender ,null  ,row_number() over (order by Gender)  from students group by Gender
            union all   select null ,null ,null    ,null   ,Score ,row_number() over (order by Score)   from students group by Score
            ) s

group by    n   

order by    n
;
```

---

```
+------+-----+---------+--------+--------+
| name | age | address | gender | score  |
+------+-----+---------+--------+--------+
| A    | 1   | abc     | F      | 5      |
+------+-----+---------+--------+--------+
| B    | 2   | def     | M      | 10     |
+------+-----+---------+--------+--------+
| C    | 3   | ghi     |        |        |
+------+-----+---------+--------+--------+
```

---

For educational purposes, here are the results of the inner query:

```
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
| name | age | address | gender | score | n |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
| A    |     |         |        |       | 1 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
| B    |     |         |        |       | 2 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
| C    |     |         |        |       | 3 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
|      | 1   |         |        |       | 1 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
|      | 2   |         |        |       | 2 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
|      | 3   |         |        |       | 3 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
|      |     | abc     |        |       | 1 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
|      |     | def     |        |       | 2 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
|      |     | ghi     |        |       | 3 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
|      |     |         | F      |       | 1 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
|      |     |         | M      |       | 2 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
|      |     |         |        | 5     | 1 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
|      |     |         |        | 10    | 2 |
+------+-----+---------+--------+-------+---+
```